# Display images from S3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs

I have Amazon AWS S3 Bucket and images inside. Every object in my bucket has its own link. When I open it a browser ask me to download the image. So, it is a download link, but not directly the link of the image in the Internet. Of course, when I put it to `<img src="https://">` it doesn't works.

So my question is *how I can display images from S3 on my client so that I will not be forced to download images instead of just watching them on the site*.

My Stack: Nest.js & React.js (TypeScript)

How I upload images:

one service:

```
const svgBuffer = Buffer.from(svgString, 'utf-8');
mainRes = await uploadFile(currency, svgBuffer);
```

another service I got uploadFile function from:

```
uploadFile = (currency: string, svg: Buffer) => {
        const uploadParams = {
            Bucket: this.config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            Body: svg,
            Key: `${currency}-chart`,
        };

        return this.s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
    };
```

How I supposed to get my images:

```
<img src=`https://${s3bucketPath}/${imagePath}`>
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a problem with object metadata. Check the metadata and validate the Content type. For example for an PNG image should be:

```
Content-Type='image/png'
```

If object's Content-Type is 'binary/octet-stream' then it will download instead of display.

Add the corresponding parameter when uploading through JavaScript SDK:

```
const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: this.config.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Body: svg,
        Key: `${currency}-chart`,
        ContentType: 'image/png',
    };
```

UPD from the author:
Add this and all gonna work

```
ContentType: 'image/svg+xml'
```

Comment: I've added  `ContentType: 'image/svg+xml'` and now all works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After the image is uploaded you have multiple options to get them without downloading them to your application.

---

The easiest one but not the best is getting them directly from the S3 Bucket.

Let's say We have the bucket: `bucket-test`, You can get URL directly in the browser:
[image: s3 bucket]

But Your object must be public which is unsafe. Moreover, it will be generating additional costs in the form of the transfer.

---

The next option is to set up CloudFront which will create a CDN for your

Then you are creating the CloudFront which points to S3 objects

Some pros

- Your bucket objects may be private.
- This is also faster as images are cached in the AWS Cloudfront edges.
- You can also set alternative names for your Cloudfront distribution and hide objects.

Your traffic looks like this:

###### When an image is not cached

USER <-> Cloudfront Edge <-> S3

###### When the image is cached:

USER <-> Cloudfront Edge

Here is how to setup the CDN: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/getting-started/S3/

Comment: the problem is completely different